# How to delete particular common record from all tables in particular schema (T SQL)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tables in a database with three schemas (schema1, schema2, schema3). Each schema has 2 tables (schema1.table1, schema1.table2, schema2.table1, schema2.table2........) each table has ID column which has values like 17, 18, 19, 20, 50 etc.  I want to delete record 19 from all tables in schema1,
something like > DELETE ID 19 from ALL tables in Schema1. Is there any way to do that?
Appreciate any help Thanks

Comment: Not built in. You'd have to write dynamic SQL.

Comment: There is no "delete from all tables" syntax. If you want a `DELETE` to run against several objects, you need several DDL statements. Writing a `DELETE` statement against 6 statements is somewhat trivial, if I am honest. What about your attempt(s) didn't work? What *were* your attempts?

Comment: @larmu trying to pull and join from sys.columns and schema did,t work. Juts an add These tables do not have any PK or FK.

Comment: "larmu"; that's a new one. Like I said, you have 6 tables; just writ the 6 statements out.

Comment: @Larnu number of tables here is an example, in reality, it's close to 100,so it will be impossible to write that many statements.

Comment: @caltta - Nope, it is not impossible. It might be tedious, but we can write code to relieve ourselves of tedious, repetitive work.

Comment: "Trying to pull and join...". What about it didn't work? One of my superpowers is writing code that writes code so that's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it could be done by Dynamic sql, you will get all your needed table into a temp table with an identity column [id].

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ---identity column will be used to iterate
(
id INT IDENTITY,
SchemaName VARCHAR(20),
TableName VARCHAR(20),
ColumnName VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
-- choose your own results with where conditions

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(20)

WHILE @COUNT <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @Schema = SchemaName FROM  #temp WHERE id = @Count
    select @table = TABLENAME FROM #temp WHERE id = @Count
    SELECT @Column = COLUMNNAME FROM #temp WHERE id = @Count
    
    SELECT @sql = 'DELECT FROM '+@Schema+'.'+@Table+ 'WHERE ID = 19'

    --PRINT @SQL
SET @Count = @Count + 1

END
```

change PRINT to Exec if your printed query looks good to you.

Comment: Thanks, @Jiacheng. Looks PRINT works but replacing with Exec, throwing error and looking for stored procedure 'could not find stored procedure'. Any idea !!!

Comment: @cal tta. not sure what's your code looks like, I didn't use stored procedures in my query. Another way is to copy the results from PRINT, then execute them.

Comment: Thanks  @Jiacheng. followed the same code. just changed the temp table name. Thanks

Comment: ok. then could you please send the result from PRINT, and the full error message when you change to EXEC (@SQL)

Comment: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 37
Could not find stored procedure 'DELECT FROM AA.tblempWHERE empID = 10'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 37
Could not find stored procedure 'DELECT FROM AA.tblempWHERE empID = 10'.

Comment: DELECT FROM AA.tblempWHERE empID = 10
DELECT FROM AA.tblempWHERE empID = 10
DELECT FROM AA.tblempWHERE empID = 10
DELECT FROM AA.tblempWHERE empID = 10
DELECT FROM AA.tblemp1WHERE empID = 10

Comment: ABOVE i got using print in the message, but it seems also there are repetitions !!! AA.tblemp has only one empid row.

Comment: i see, first problem is DELECT,,, change it to DELETE, i might type wrong in code,, but it's obviously..XD

Comment: another thing is, add a space before where, otherwise it's a wrong syntex. And seems you all your desired table is AA.tblemp. could you do SELECT * FROM #temp(your table) and let me know what are stored here,

Comment: Good to know, i'l be appreciate if you could vote my answer... XD